# How to get FormControl Validator in HTML view

Tags: angular2-forms

I'm using Reactive form. I want to get Validator of FormControl in view like this:

```
<span *ngIf="productForm.controls.ProductName.validator?.required" class="required-field">*</span>
```

My component code is like this :

```
    this.productForm = new FormGroup({
            'ProductName': new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
})
```

Is there any way to know on view that ProductName have a validator and that is required

Answer (score 0):

Can be checked using

```
*ngIf = "productForm.controls.Productname.errors.required"
```

to check if the input has a required validator.